DigiKam - Show hidden folders
In Digikam, I want to see all the folders in the album view. I have a folder called .thumbnails that doesn't show. I can't find any options to enable hidden folders (or whatever these .folders are called).
Is there anyone who knows how to enable this option?

They're called dot files/folders, that might be an option to look for.

In Ubuntu "files" (Nautilus from the Terminal) you will see these files and foders if you hold CTRL and hit H - do it once more to hide them again. Maybe the same in Digikam?
